# How can I keep my results from overwriting themselves in Mocha Junit

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, mocha.js

I'm using Cypress with Mocha Junit to do e2e testing for React in Chrome. The default behavior is for it to have one single output for results each time it runs my tests, and it overwrites the file every time. I'd like to have it keep these files in like a log.

The config is in a JSON file that looks like this:

```
}
  "projectId": "XXXXXX",
  "reporter": "junit",
  "reporterOptions": {
    "mochaFile": "./cypress/results/my-test-output.xml",
    "toConsole": true
  }
}
```

I'd like to do something like

```
var date = new Date();
"mochaFile": "./cypress/results/my-test-output${date}.xml",
```

Obviously this isn't valid JSON. How can I rig this up to make it generate something unique each time?

Comment: Why wouldn't that be valid in JSON? As long as it's a `String` you're fine.

Comment: Consider renaming the title of your question as this is specific behaviour to the reporter you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs,

> Results XML filename can contain [hash]

Also, if you check the junit reporter [source](https://github.com/michaelleeallen/mocha-junit-reporter/blob/master/index.js), you can see how is doing it:

```
...
this.writeXmlToDisk(xml, this._options.mochaFile);
...

MochaJUnitReporter.prototype.writeXmlToDisk = function(xml, filePath){
  if (filePath) {
    if (filePath.indexOf('[hash]') !== -1) {
      filePath = filePath.replace('[hash]', md5(xml));
    } ...
```

So, you could just have:

```
"mochaFile": "./cypress/results/my-test-output[hash].xml"
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do here. As you can see all you need to do is wrap your JSON in backticks. Except that I'd suggest you use `Date.now()` instead of `new Date()`.

```js
let date = Date.now();
let json = `{
  "projectId": "XXXXXX",
  "reporter": "junit",
  "reporterOptions": {
    "mochaFile": "./cypress/results/my-test-output-${date}.xml",
    "toConsole": true
  }
}`

let parsedJson = JSON.parse(json)
console.log(parsedJson.reporterOptions.mochaFile)
```

Compared to a hash this even has the advantage of historization.

Comment: The issue with this is that it is a .JSON file, not a js file. any kind oflogic will not be considered valid JSON, as far as i know. But I'm also relatively new at this kind of thing.

Comment: Within Strings, you can do whatever you like in JSON.